# getting started with py automation

Tags: ctypes, pywin32, win32com, pywinauto, win32gui

hi I m new to these python automating thing and I wonder how can I automate to iterate thorough different windows and how to behave with child windows and also iterate thorough different menus and submenus to choose one?
I maybe wrong so pls correct me but as far as I've understood:
'pywinauto' seems incomplete  yet and also have problems with python version 3.8, 'ctypes' creation purpose seems for other things (like working with c++ written files and not perticularly for windows api), with 'win32gui' I can select a window by name and bring it front but I don't know how to go different menus and child windows, and don't know about the 'win32com' objects.
win32gui documentations seem incomplete and do not have descriptions for different functions like

```
http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui.html
```

pls suggest sources and also a simple code to about how to get submenus open
thank U
btw with this code I can get application handle and menus by manually selecting them

```
import win32gui
import time
time.sleep(5)
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow ()
hmenu1=win32gui.GetMenu(hwnd)
```

and with this I can bring it front

```
win32gui.BringWindowToTop(hwnd)
```

pls tell me how to open menus
btw these codes seem to get sub menus but don't know how to open menus with them

```
hmenu1=win32gui.GetMenu(hwnd)
hmenu2 = (win32gui.GetSubMenu(hmenu1, 2))
hmenu3 = win32gui.GetSubMenu(hmenu2, 5)
```

and I have no clue how to deal with child windows and how to select them or get their handlers

Comment: Try `win32gui.EnumWindows()`/

Comment: yeah I know that, thank U but what about working with menus? how to open them for i.e. how I can open 'view -> template -> load template' from an application?

Comment: Why are you trying to learn low level Win32 API? pywinauto already wraps this technology (and modern MS UI Automation API as well) in a more Pythonic way. See the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).